# htaccess rewrite or php url exploding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying/attempting to create my own MVC. I am really trying to manipulate the url. I am trying to get several parameters to form a full URL.
I want to turn

```
http://example.com/?action=account&user=JohnDoe
```

to

```
http://example.com/account/JohnDoe
```

But I cant seem to get the .htaccess file to work right :/

This is what I have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]
```

When I go to `http://example.com/account/JohnDoe` I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing one parameter, try this

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: That did work, but is there any way to i will be able to go to `http://example.com/login` without it erroring out because it wants 2 parameters?

Comment: You can create a new RewriteRule for that

Comment: Thanks again! That all worked *I ended up with* 
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^([accounts]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]`
`rewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than set up a mod_rewrite rule for that specific URL, why not put an entire framework in place?

mod_rewrite as follows:

```
#URI PATH CONSTRUCTION
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?string=$1  [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Then have your index.php file break up $_REQUEST['string'] into an array that you can test to direct the request to where it needs to go

```
if (isset($_GET['string'])) {

    //DEALS WITH GET PARAMETERS
    if (strstr($_GET['string'],"?") !== false) {
                $pos = 0;
                $tailstr = substr($_GET['string'],$pos);
                $endpos = strpos($tailstr, "?");
                $endpos = $endpos + strlen("?");
                $string = substr($_GET['string'],$pos,$endpos);
    } else {
                $string = $_GET['string'];
    }

    $path = explode("/",$_GET['string']);

}

//Depth to 5 levels
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
     if (!isset($path[$i])) $path[$i] = null;
}

global $path;
```

You now have a global array containing the individual elements in the URI

eg

http://example.com/account/JohnDoe

would give you:

```
$path[0] = 'account'
$path[1] = 'JohnDoe'
$path[2] = ''
$path[3] = ''
$path[4] = ''
```